# Diferencia entre std::uninitialized_copy y std::copy?

Tags: c++

Estoy probando ambas y siempre me devuelven lo mismo. Hay algún caso especifico donde solo se pueda usar una de las dos ?

---

//Ejemplo 1:

```
std::allocator<int> alloc;
int arr[5]{7,7,7,7,7 };
int *arr2 = new int[5]{5,5,5,5,5};

std::uninitialized_copy(arr, arr + 5, arr2);
//std::copy(arr, arr + 5, arr2);

for (std::size_t i{ 0 }; i < 5;++i)
    std::cout << *(arr2+i) << " ";*/
//output de ambos algoritmos: 7 7 7 7 7;
```

---

//Ejemplo 2:

```
std::allocator<int> alloc;
int *arr{ alloc.allocate(5) };
int *arr2 = new int[5]{5,5,5,5,5};

//std::uninitialized_copy(arr, arr + 5, arr2);
std::copy(arr, arr + 5, arr2);

for (std::size_t i{ 0 }; i < 5;++i)
    std::cout << *(arr2+i) << " ";
//output para ambos algoritmos: -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451*/
```

Answer (score 4):

`std::unitialized_copy` se utiliza cuando `arr2` solo apunta a una región de memoria no inicializada. Por ejemplo si has usado `malloc`. De esta forma `std::uninitialized_copy` se encarga, en primer lugar, de inicializar el contenedor que va a alojar los elementos y, posteriormente, realiza la copia.

Por contra, `std::copy` se limita a copiar los elementos.

¿Y qué es una región de memoria no inicializada?

Se entiende por memoria no inicializada aquella que ha sido reservada con, por ejemplo `malloc`. Una función heredada de C que únicamente reserva memoria, es decir, no invoca ningún constructor de forma implícita.

Si hablamos de tipos nativos (puntero a `int`, por ejemplo), no hay diferencia. Pero si hablamos de objetos entonces la cosa cambia ya que un objeto no inicializado no es seguro de utilizar puesto que no tiene un estado válido.

Un ejemplo:

```
void* memoria = malloc(1000);
std::string * str = reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(memoria);

*str = "abcdef"; // Más que probable error en ejecución.
```

Entonces, ¿Cuándo **no** se puede usar `std::copy`?

Básicamente cuando tenemos una región de memoria **no inicializada**.

Un ejemplo tonto sacada de la [documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_copy). al sustituir `std::uninitialized_copy` por `std::copy` obtenemos un bonito error de segmentación:

```
int main()
{
    const char *v[] = {"This", "is", "an", "example"};

    auto sz = std::size(v);

    if(void *pbuf = std::aligned_alloc(alignof(std::string), sizeof(std::string) * sz))
    {
        try
        {
            auto first = static_cast<std::string*>(pbuf);
            auto last = std::copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), first);

            for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it)
                std::cout << *it << '_';

            std::destroy(first, last);
        }
        catch(...) {}
        std::free(pbuf);
    }
}
```

Por contra, usar `std::uninitialized_copy` cuando ya tenemos la memoria inicializada podría crear fugas de memoria, puesto que no se va a intentar destruir lo que ya existe en la memoria. Al inicializar la memoria se invocará el constructor correspondiente y eso podría hacer que se perdiesen punteros a regiones de memoria reservadas por el objeto que existía en esa región de memoria.